# Yii2: getting error while page load '$model not defined'

Tags: yii2

I have developed form to allow owner to create team. code is:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'team-create-form', 'action' => ['site/create-team-form'], 'options' => array('role' => 'form')]);
<div class="col-lg-10 form-group" id="createTeamForm" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<?= $form->field($model, 'team_name',['template' => "{label}\t{input}\n{error}"])->textInput(array('placeholder'=>'Enter team name....')); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">
  <?= $form->field($model, 'team_description',['template' => "{label}\t{input}\n{error}"])->textInput(array('placeholder'=>'Enter team Description....')); ?>
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-2">
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'id' => 'tsubmit', 'style' =>       'margin-top: 22.5px; margin-right: 15px;']) ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried loading the page with the above code but it is showing me error "$model not defined". How to resolve that. Am i need to add something in the main-local.php???

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {

        $collection1 = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('users');
        $teamid = $collection1->findOne(array('username' => $model->email_address));

        $session->set('id', $teamid['_id']);
        $session->set('name', $teamid['name']);
        $session->set('username', $model->email_address);

        $collection2 = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('teamdashboard');
        $teams = $collection2->find(array('admin' => $model->email_address));

        $model1 = new TeamCreateForm();
        return $this->render('dashboard', ['model'=>$model1, 'teams'=> $teams]);

    } elseif($session->isActive){
        $username = $session->get('username');
        $collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('users');
        $teams = $collection->findOne(array('username' => $username));

        return $this->render('dashboard', ['teams'=>$teams]);

    }else{
        $this->layout = 'index';
        return $this->render('login', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

I have renamed the productpage as dashboard for better understanding.

Now when i run this & logs in, The address bar url shows url:..../web/index.php?r=site/login whereas it should show me url:..../web/index.php?r=site/dashboard & shows me the view of dashboard.

When i refresh the page, i brings me back to the login...

Comment: are u sending the $model to view??

Comment: i am not sending $model to views bcoz if i do so then the url on address bar remains same as that of before dashboard. that will cause problem.

Comment: i agree with @Mihai, please gothrough the documentations http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the $model to the view. The view only knows variables if you send it to it.

I have no idea what you mean with the address bar. The address bar has nothing to do with what you send to the view.

**EDIT**
Your entire way of thinking is strange. Why would u show different views depending if the person is registered or not?

return $this->render('dashboard', ['teams'=>$teams]);
return $this->render('login', ['model' => $model]);

User redirect with parameters to move the customer to another page. Having an URL like /login that actually shows a dashboard is not logical.

Comment: Thats right but after login when it redirects me to index.php?r=site/productpage from index.php?r=site/login, it has to show index.php?r=site/productpage. but on my address bar it still shows index.php?r=site/login & showing me the content of productpage view. It should not happen....

Comment: how do you redirect, show us the controller function.

Comment: I have updated the question with the controller function check

Answer (score 0):

Did you use $model in dashboard view? If you do - you need to pass it (the same way as the login).

Comment: You are exactly right. I know this. But when i do so with render function i am getting the url problem on address bar see the comments with Mihai P below.