# Yii2: How to send multiple parameters in redirect

Tags: yii2

I am redirecting from login page to dashboard page. I want to send teams variable that contain my existing data about the teams. I have tried following but that is not working...

```
return $this->redirect(array('site/dashboard', ['model' => $model1, 'teams' => $teams]));
```

model1 is getting sent but not teams...

Answer (score 16):

As arogachev already pointed, the second param is the code, BUT the first param is an array. In order to put some parameters, you need to do something like this:

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/dashboard','id' => 1, 'var1' => 'test']);
```

So for every param you put extra item in the array where the key is the name and the value is the value of the get param.

Cheers!

Comment: it doesn't work!!!. still show error for second paramater even if i pass it in the single array. If it works with you then tell me how it is accessible in view...

Comment: $model1 is accessible in view & not showing any issue with conventional method.

Comment: Can you post how do you try to send the params? And what's the error?

Comment: The question i have asked is in reference with my previous question  just go through it & you will come to know why i am using redirect function instead of render.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358554/yii2-getting-error-while-page-load-model-not-defined/27368352?noredirect=1#comment43228305_27368352

Comment: @TihomilKulev: he asking about passing variables to view, and not building url for redirect.

Comment: @Shaggie: Read my answer carefully again. You can not pass variables to view in redirect() method. You can just build url and set status code.

Answer (score 4):

Change your line to following. Since you have already used array no need for square brackets.

```
return $this->redirect(array('site/dashboard', 'model' => $model1, 'teams' => $teams));
```

Answer (score 1):

See official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect%28%29-detail) about this method.
The second parameter is status code, so what you are doing is completely wrong.
Passing the variables here does not make any sense because immediately another action starts to load.
You should pass variables to view in action to which you redirect and not where actual redirect happens.